# C++ macro function expansion based on the macro function arguments

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Some systems I use don't have a logging library I'm using, which is OK for well-tested code on production runs --- the logging library is mostly for debugging and testing.  On my main development machine, and on a couple of servers I frequently run experiments on, the logging library exists.  But occasionally I need to farm out experiments to another server with many more nodes and cores but that does *not* have the logging library.

The library (Google glog) provides, for example, the following macro functions:

```
LOG(INFO) << "Insert my message here.";
LOG(FATAL) << "Insert another message here.";
```

So, what I've done is defined the following:

```
#ifdef NOLOGGING
    #define MYLOG(i,m) std::cerr << #i << ": " << m << "\n";
#else
    #define MYLOG(i,m) LOG(i) << m ;
#endif
```

Using those definitions, I can now write statements like this:

```
MYLOG(INFO, "My info message");
MYLOG(FATAL,"My fatal message");
```

If compiled with flag `-DNOLOGGING`, the last two statements will be expanded to:

```
std::cerr << "INFO" << ": " << "My info message" << "\n";
std::cerr << "FATAL" << ": " << "My fatal message" << "\n";
```

Wherease, if the `-DNOLOGGING` flag is *not* used in compilation, they will be expanded to:

```
LOG(INFO) << "My info message";
LOG(FATAL) << "My fatal message";
```

---

The solution I've described above is satisfactory, but not ideal.

Ideally, when I don't have acces to the logging library, statements like `MYLOG(FATAL,"foo")` would expand to statements that print to `std::cerr`; *however*, statments like `MYLOG(INFO,"bar")` would expand to nothing.  In other words, when I can't use the logging library, I want statements like `MYLOG(INFO,"bar")` to be ignored.  The idea is that I don't care too much about log messages of the `INFO` severity when I'm using the servers without the logging library, but I do still want to see messages of the `FATAL` severity.

**How, if possible, can I do this using only preprocessor directives?**

Comment: Why not simply go with a function that uses preprocessor directives? Like void log(string target, string message){ #ifdef NOLOGGING if(target.compare("INFO") == 0) { ... } ... }, called like log("INFO", "my info message");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it solely with preprocessing directives, since the preprocessor doesn't really give you the necessary mechanisms to guide macro expansion based on the arguments to the macro.

That said, you *can* perpetrate some mildly ugly hacks that will work.  Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MYLOG_ERR  1
#define MYLOG_INFO 0

#define P(a,b) a##b

#define MYLOG(x,y) do { if (P(MYLOG_,x)) { std::cerr << y << std::endl; } } while (0)


int main(void)
{
    MYLOG(ERR, "err");
    MYLOG(INFO, "info");
}
```

This approach relies on the compiler's optimizer to recognize some common idioms, such as `do { ... } while (0)` and `if (0)` / `if (1)` to optimize away compile-time known conditions.  But, I think it'll give you what you want.

Comment: I would do `#define MYLOG(x,y) (P(MYLOG_,x) ? void(std::cerr << y << std::endl) : void())` instead.

Comment: @Simple:  Also valid.  I actually started writing this with `?:` first, but I decided that `void` expressions were just a bit obscure.  Both approaches work.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is *very* interesting.  I suppose, given the limitations of the preprocessor macro language, I might be better-off defining macros like `MYLOG_FATAL(m)` and `MYLOG_INFO(m)`.